# Getting the javascript object data into a clean form in java

Tags: javascript, java

I am passing a `javascript` object to a java using `AJAX` call.But the problem is that the data is getting transferred wherein I need to do a lot of irrelevant work to clean that data.Here is the javascript code which does the thing.

```
var tableObject = $('#priorityTbl tbody tr').map(function (i) {
        var row = {};
        var count=0;
        $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
            var rowName = columns[i];
            row[rowName] = $(this).text();
        });

        priorityObj.push(row);
    });
```

This does my work and I pass the object as post to java.In the servlet I get the data from the `parameterMap`.But the data is in the below format as `key:value`

```
Object[0][priority_name] : [Ljava.lang.String;@5f91c02d
Object[0][priority_status] : [Ljava.lang.String;@59dffb5f
Object[0][undefined] : [Ljava.lang.String;@7ff04811
Object[1][priority_name] : [Ljava.lang.String;@780b95b5
Object[1][priority_status] : [Ljava.lang.String;@4091dba5
Object[1][undefined] : [Ljava.lang.String;@27eb4ec1
```

How shall I change so that I may get it in java in the form priority_name-1,priority_status-0...etc in such form?

Comment: Show your Java code.  Are you using JAX-RS?  JAX-RS will do the low-level conversion from JSON (a text format for representing data to be sent over the network) to objects in Java.

Comment: You can use jquery.param(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to covert your object to a String representation for sending to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Got an approach.I tried `JSON.stringify` and now it is much cleaner.